# Confused about intellisense and js files that are needed

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Do I still need to declare this at the top of my fiels when I want to use intelisense in VS2010? Also does it need to be in exactly the first two lines?

```
/// <reference path="jquery-1.6.2.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery.validate.js" />
```

Also should I declare the full path such as "/script/jquery-1.6.2.js" ?  What I do have is that along with the js scripts I have some files like this:

```
jquery-1.7.2-vsdoc.js
```

I'm not sure about all this. Can someone explain which are needed for me if I am using jQuery with my VS2010.

Thanks

Comment: If your question is answered please mark it. Ty

Answer (score 1):

If you want intelisense you need to add references to your js files and they must be on top of the file. References should have relative paths.  That means if your js file is in the same directory as jquery.js you only need to add

```
/// <reference path="jquery-1.6.7.js" />
```

If you are in the child directory you use

```
/// <reference path="../jquery-1.7.2.js" />
```

jquery-1.7.2-vsdoc.js file gives intelisense ([homepage](http://appendto.com/community/jquery-vsdoc)), function definitions and parameters.

If you have a lot of javascript on your page I suggest that you split it up in plugins and functions and with cross references you can get intelisense for them ([so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10171388/javascript-documentation-from-vsdoc)). However on production server you should minify them in to one file to save http requests.